# Firebase + Capacitor Ionic Angular: @angular/fire Analytics Module not working

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire

I am developing an app using Capacitor, Ionic and Angular. I implemented firebase using the @angular/fire package and configured it in the app.module. Firestore and Remote Config work great, but I have issues with Analytics and Performance monitoring. When including their respective modules nothing happens, and I cannot see any data in my Firebase Console. I installed the Google Analytics Debugger Chrome extension, and I see the following log output:

```
[WDS] Live Reloading enabled.
js?l=dataLayer:97        _                 _
  __ _| |_ __ _  __ _   (_)___
 / _` | __/ _` |/ _` |  | / __|
| (_| | || (_| | (_| |_ | \__ \
 \__, |\__\__,_|\__, (_)/ |___/
 |___/          |___/ |__/


js?l=dataLayer:97 Processing commands (0)
js?l=dataLayer:97 Processing commands (1)
js?l=dataLayer:97 Processing data layer push: {event: "gtm.dom"}
js?l=dataLayer:97 No tags fired for event: gtm.dom
js?l=dataLayer:97 Processing commands (1)
js?l=dataLayer:97 Processing data layer push: {event: "gtm.load"}
js?l=dataLayer:97 No tags fired for event: gtm.load
js?l=dataLayer:97 Processing commands (1)
js?l=dataLayer:97 Processing data layer command: ["js", Thu Jul 23 2020 15:29:20 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)]
js?l=dataLayer:97 Processing commands (1)
js?l=dataLayer:97 Processing data layer command: ["config", "G-EFXK7WP1L3", {firebase_id: "em9ORiiXLIobdTTC-vYtV7", origin: "firebase", update: true}]
js?l=dataLayer:97 Processing commands (1)
js?l=dataLayer:97 Processing data layer command: ["config", "G-EFXK7WP1L3", {page_path: "/home", screen_class: "sw-home", update: true}]
js?l=dataLayer:97 Processing commands (1)
js?l=dataLayer:97 Processing data layer command: ["config", "G-EFXK7WP1L3", {page_title: "Switch", update: true}]
js?l=dataLayer:97 Processing commands (1)
js?l=dataLayer:97 Processing data layer command: ["config", "G-EFXK7WP1L3", {update: true, screen_name: "home"}]
js?l=dataLayer:97 Processing commands (1)
js?l=dataLayer:97 Processing data layer command: ["event", "screen_view", {firebase_screen_class: "sw-home", firebase_screen_id: -2048229402, screen_name: "home", page_path: "/home", firebase_event_origin: "auto", firebase_screen: "home", outlet: "primary", page_title: "Switch", screen_class: "sw-home", send_to: "G-EFXK7WP1L3"}]
home:1 A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://google.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.
home:1 A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at https://google.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.
js?l=dataLayer:97 Processing commands (1)
js?l=dataLayer:97 Processing data layer command: ["config", "G-EFXK7WP1L3", {update: true, user_id: null}]
```

As I understand this, events are created but are not sent to Google. Also, in the network tab, I don't see any POST requests made to the /collect endpoint. I also tried enabling DEBUG mode using the dependency injection but nothing changed.

What I tried was commenting out the AngularFireAnalyticsModule import, then importing firebase and firebase/analytics and calling firebase.analytics() in the AppModule's constructor. When I did this and enabled the Chrome Plugin, I was able to see some events in my Firebase Console DebugView, and the log output was as follows:

```
  __ _| |_ __ _  __ _   (_)___
 / _` | __/ _` |/ _` |  | / __|
| (_| | || (_| | (_| |_ | \__ \
 \__, |\__\__,_|\__, (_)/ |___/
 |___/          |___/ |__/


js?l=dataLayer:97 Processing commands (0)
js?l=dataLayer:97 Processing commands (1)
js?l=dataLayer:97 Processing data layer push: {event: "gtm.dom"}
js?l=dataLayer:97 No tags fired for event: gtm.dom
client:52 [WDS] Live Reloading enabled.
js?l=dataLayer:97 Processing commands (1)
js?l=dataLayer:97 Processing GTAG command: ["js", Thu Jul 23 2020 15:52:19 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)]
js?l=dataLayer:97 No tags fired for event: gtm.js
js?l=dataLayer:97 Processing commands (1)
js?l=dataLayer:97 Processing GTAG command: ["config", "G-EFXK7WP1L3", {firebase_id: "em9ORiiXLIobdTTC-vYtV7", origin: "firebase", update: true}]
js?l=dataLayer:97 GTAG Command: "config", target: "G-EFXK7WP1L3", configuration: {firebase_id: "em9ORiiXLIobdTTC-vYtV7", origin: "firebase", update: true}
js?id=G-EFXK7WP1L3&l=dataLayer&cx=c:134        _                 _
  __ _| |_ __ _  __ _   (_)___
 / _` | __/ _` |/ _` |  | / __|
| (_| | || (_| | (_| |_ | \__ \
 \__, |\__\__,_|\__, (_)/ |___/
 |___/          |___/ |__/


js?id=G-EFXK7WP1L3&l=dataLayer&cx=c:134 Processing commands (3)
js?id=G-EFXK7WP1L3&l=dataLayer&cx=c:134 Processing data layer push: {event: "gtm.dom", gtm.uniqueEventId: 1}
js?id=G-EFXK7WP1L3&l=dataLayer&cx=c:134 No tags fired for event: gtm.dom
js?id=G-EFXK7WP1L3&l=dataLayer&cx=c:134 Processing GTAG command: ["js", Thu Jul 23 2020 15:52:19 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)]
js?id=G-EFXK7WP1L3&l=dataLayer&cx=c:134 Tag fired: {function: "__gct", vtp_trackingId: "G-EFXK7WP1L3", vtp_adFeatures: false, vtp_sessionDuration: 0, vtp_googleSignals: ["macro", 1], vtp_foreignTld: ["macro", 2], vtp_restrictDomain: ["macro", 3], vtp_eventSettings: ["map", "app_store_subscription_convert", ["map", "blacklisted", false, "conversion", true], "app_store_subscription_renew", ["map", "blacklisted", false, "conversion", true], "first_open", ["map", "blacklisted", false, "conversion", true], "in_app_purchase", ["map", "blacklisted", false, "conversion", true], "purchase", ["map", "blacklisted", false, "conversion", true]], vtp_dynamicEventSettings: ["map", "edit_rules", ["list"], "synthesis_rules", ["list"]], tag_id: 7}
js?id=G-EFXK7WP1L3&l=dataLayer&cx=c:134 Loaded existing client id: 612189906.1595510156
js?id=G-EFXK7WP1L3&l=dataLayer&cx=c:134 Event would be batched, but batching is disabled in debug mode.
js?id=G-EFXK7WP1L3&l=dataLayer&cx=c:134 Sending event "page_view" to undefined
js?id=G-EFXK7WP1L3&l=dataLayer&cx=c:134 Request parameters:
js?id=G-EFXK7WP1L3&l=dataLayer&cx=c:134 v: 2
js?id=G-EFXK7WP1L3&l=dataLayer&cx=c:134 tid: G-EFXK7WP1L3
js?id=G-EFXK7WP1L3&l=dataLayer&cx=c:134 gtm: 2oe7f0
js?id=G-EFXK7WP1L3&l=dataLayer&cx=c:134 _p: 536560896
js?id=G-EFXK7WP1L3&l=dataLayer&cx=c:134 sr: 375x812
js?id=G-EFXK7WP1L3&l=dataLayer&cx=c:134 _dbg: 1
js?id=G-EFXK7WP1L3&l=dataLayer&cx=c:134 ul: it-it
js?id=G-EFXK7WP1L3&l=dataLayer&cx=c:134 _fid: em9ORiiXLIobdTTC-vYtV7
js?id=G-EFXK7WP1L3&l=dataLayer&cx=c:134 cid: 612189906.1595510156
js?id=G-EFXK7WP1L3&l=dataLayer&cx=c:134 Event parameters:
js?id=G-EFXK7WP1L3&l=dataLayer&cx=c:134 en: page_view
js?id=G-EFXK7WP1L3&l=dataLayer&cx=c:134 ep.origin: firebase
js?id=G-EFXK7WP1L3&l=dataLayer&cx=c:134 Shared parameters:
js?id=G-EFXK7WP1L3&l=dataLayer&cx=c:134 dl: http://localhost/home
js?id=G-EFXK7WP1L3&l=dataLayer&cx=c:134 dr: http://localhost:8100/home
js?id=G-EFXK7WP1L3&l=dataLayer&cx=c:134 dt: Switch
js?id=G-EFXK7WP1L3&l=dataLayer&cx=c:134 sid: 1595512286
js?id=G-EFXK7WP1L3&l=dataLayer&cx=c:134 sct: 2
js?id=G-EFXK7WP1L3&l=dataLayer&cx=c:134 seg: 1
js?id=G-EFXK7WP1L3&l=dataLayer&cx=c:134 Sending request: https://www.google-analytics.com/g/collect?v=2&tid=G-EFXK7WP1L3&gtm=2oe7f0&_p=536560896&sr=375x812&_dbg=1&ul=it-it&_fid=em9ORiiXLIobdTTC-vYtV7&cid=612189906.1595510156&_s=1&dl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fhome&dr=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8100%2Fhome&dt=Switch&sid=1595512286&sct=2&seg=1&en=page_view&ep.origin=firebase
js?id=G-EFXK7WP1L3&l=dataLayer&cx=c:134 Processing GTAG command: ["config", "G-EFXK7WP1L3", {firebase_id: "em9ORiiXLIobdTTC-vYtV7", origin: "firebase", _uei: 3}]
js?id=G-EFXK7WP1L3&l=dataLayer&cx=c:134 GTAG Command: "config", target: "G-EFXK7WP1L3", configuration: {firebase_id: "em9ORiiXLIobdTTC-vYtV7", origin: "firebase", _uei: 3}
js?id=G-EFXK7WP1L3&l=dataLayer&cx=c:134 No tags fired for event: gtag.config
js?l=dataLayer:97 Processing commands (1)
js?l=dataLayer:97 Processing data layer push: {event: "gtm.load"}
js?l=dataLayer:97 No tags fired for event: gtm.load
js?id=G-EFXK7WP1L3&l=dataLayer&cx=c:134 Processing commands (1)
js?id=G-EFXK7WP1L3&l=dataLayer&cx=c:134 Processing data layer push: {event: "gtm.load", gtm.uniqueEventId: 7}
js?id=G-EFXK7WP1L3&l=dataLayer&cx=c:134 No tags fired for event: gtm.load
```

I also noticed POST calls to the /collect endpoint, so everything is working as expected.
The question is - why isn't the Module working correctly? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this when you have your app built and running on a real device?  If so, it won't work.  It only works when in a browser.  You'll need something like this cordova wrapper https://github.com/chemerisuk/cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics for firebase analytics.  I can't find where I found that answer, but I have the same problem in my app.  Only my PWA version logs to firebase analytics, when its on a device nothing is sent.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. The problem itself had to do with the version of @angular/fire used - 6.0.2 has a bug preventing Performance and Analytics from sending events; 6.0.0 works fine. But I just ran into the problem You mention, Analytics, Performance and even Remote Config seem not to work on a real device. Is this correct? Will Firestore work? Is there any workaround other then using native plugins?

Comment: I haven't found a solution for firebase analytics, I'm pretty sure its by design. Can't comment on the other features.  Its a side project of mine and I've got other higher priority items that need to be fixed.  I was mainly using it for error tracking so I switched to Sentry for that (which I also still don't have fully set up with source maps but its good enough)

Comment: Any progress with Performance Monitoring and Angular Fire? Angular Fire supports Firestore, Analytics, and Remote Config in an Ionic/Angular/Capacitor app. Works on my devices.